# Using getElementsByTagName then using getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the value from an input with an ID inside a LI element.

But when I call the `getElementsByTagName()[0].getElementsById()` I get the error `numLi[i].getElementById is not a function` being numLi an array with LI elements. Here's my whole js code

```
$('form').submit(function()
{
    var headOne = document.getElementById('inputHead').value;
    var archive = document.getElementById('inputPara').value;
    var numLi = document.getElementById('uList').getElementsByTagName('li');
    var tagsToPost = '';
    for(i = 0;i<numLi.length;i++)
    {
        var ff = numLi[i].getElementById('tagOne');

       if(i<=numLi-1)
       {
            tagsToPost = tagsToPost + ff.value + ',';
       }
       else
       {
        tagsToPost = tagsToPost + ff.value;
       }
    }

});
```

And the html part I'm trying to access

```
 <form action="javascript:void(0);">
<div class="col-md-3">

    <div id="enlacesList">
        <ul id="uList">

                <li class='listaLink'><input type="text" id="tagOne" class="tags" placeholder="Tags" autocomplete="off"></li>   
                <li class='listaLink'><input type="text" id="tagOne" class="tags" placeholder="Tags" autocomplete="off"></li>      

        </ul>
    </div>
     <button id="addgregador" type="button" autocomplete="off"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button><button id="desadd" type="button" autocomplete="off"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9" id="containerTexto">
    <div id="textoPregunta">
        <div id="textHeading"><input type="text" name="headingOne" id="inputHead" placeholder="Titulo de la pregunta" autocomplete="off"></div>
        <div id="textContent"><textarea id="inputPara" rows="33" cols="84" placeholder="Respuesta, explicación..." autocomplete="off"></textarea></div>
        <input type="submit" id="editOk" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary" autocomplete="off"><input type="reset" id="editNot" value="Cancelar" class="btn btn-danger" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>
```

The program breaks in the line `var ff = numLi[i].getElementById('tagOne');`.

Comment: Why do you have multiple elements on the page with the same id?

Comment: @epascarello they are created with the two buttons down the `ul` tag, I only used the same ID because I have in mind calling them by ID, a solution to my problem may be using `getElementsByTagName('input')[0]`, instead of `getElementById(''tagOne')`

Comment: You just can't have multiple elements with the same id. Use classes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getElementById` function is defined only on `document`, not on DOM nodes in general. See its [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). This is because ids should be unique at document level, so it doesn't make sense to scope it to an individual element.

So first of all, don't use the same id for multiple elements in one document. If you have only one input per `LI` element, remove the id attribute and get them for example like this.

```
var ff = numLi[i].children[0];
```

Comment: I was aware that I should not use same IDs on differents elements, but as they were only there to be called by the js (because I thought my way would work) I just used them, but now I realise I should have use your way or `numLi[i].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Just call document.getElementById("tagOne").value to get the value.

ID fields must be unique in your html as well, so you need to rename the second one to tagTwo or something. The ID allows you to go straight to them when you use getElementById. It's improper HTML and generally throws errors for you to have two elements with the same ID field. (indexing by ID)

I don't think you can use getElementById on anything other than the document, though. Its been awhile since I took my web development class at UCSD.

Comment: Indeed, you can only call `getElementById` on the document.

Answer (score -1):

You wanna do something like:
 var x = getElementsByTagName()[0].id
document.getElementsById(x).innerHTML = ....?

this can be condensed to :

```
document.getElementsById(document.getElementsByTagName("Example:Div")[0].id)
```